# Document Ready not firing when expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site and all the pages get loaded with ajax.

I will load the first page and using

```
if (window.jQuery) {
    alert('jQuery is loaded');
}
```

it alerts that jquery has been loaded every time.

I also have in the page the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Document Ready');
}
```

The document ready alert doesn't fire the first time however works the second time around.

What has to happen for the document to be ready?

I don't understand why it doesn't work the first time around.

I use the following to load the page:

```
$('#load-page').load(''+base_href+''+page+'', 'show=all'+show_field_id+''+show_default_sort+'');
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
   });
```

I think you didn't close the code right.

Comment: Hi, sorry I have closed it right I just manually typed it in this post. It is definitely typed correctly also as it fires the second time around. Dan

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot a closing parenthesis in your method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Document Ready');
}); // <= be sure to close the ready method
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I have closed it right I just manually typed it in this post. It is definitely typed correctly also as it fires the second time around. Dan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expecting document.ready, you probably want to make use of [the third parameter to `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - the `complete` callback:

```
$('#load-page').load(''+base_href+page, 'show=all'+show_field_id+show_default_sort, function() {
  alert('load complete');
});
```

Of course, you could not use a lambda function here and instead use a function pointer:

```
function on_loaded() {
  alert('load complete');
}

$('#load-page').load(''+base_href+page, 'show=all'+show_field_id+show_default_sort, on_loaded);
```